# Read a textbox line by line and treat it as a separate text

Tags: c#, richtextbox, shapes, gdi

This is the code I use to draw rectangles from the RichTexbox text:

```
    try
    {
        pictureBox1.Image = null;
        bm = new Bitmap(OrgPic.Width, OrgPic.Height);

        //Location
        string spli1 = ScriptBox.Text; var p = spli1.Split('(', ')')[1];
        string spli2 = (p.ToString().Split(',', ',')[1]);

        string source = spli2;
        string loc_1 = string.Concat(source.Where(c => !char.IsWhiteSpace(c)));
        string[] coords = loc_1.Split('.');
        Point lp = new Point(int.Parse(coords[0]), int.Parse(coords[1])); ;
        Console_.Text += $"This Lines {ScriptBox.LinesCount}";
        Console_.Text += "\n" + "split1: " + spli1.ToString();
        Console_.Text += "\n" + "split2: " + loc_1.ToString();
        Console_.Text += "\n" + "cords: " + coords.ToString();
        Console_.Text += "\n" + "lp_Point: " + lp.ToString();

        //Color
        string color = ScriptBox.Text; var r = Color.FromName(color.Split('(', ',')[1]);
        string colors = (r.ToString().Split('.', ']')[1]);
        Console_.Text += "\n" + "Color final:" + colors.ToString();
        Console_.Text += "\n" + "Color Sin split:" + r.ToString();



        Color f = Color.FromName(colors);
        Pen pen = new Pen(f);
        pen.Width = 4;
        gF = Graphics.FromImage(bm);
        gF.DrawRectangle(pen, lp.X, lp.Y, 100, 60);
        pictureBox1.Image = bm;

    }
    catch (Exception)
    {

    }
```

I basically search for the word **Rect.Draw** followed by the **color. [selected color]** and the coordinates in which to place the rectangle.
The problem is that when I go through the entire RichTexbox for the functions, it only draws the rectangle once, I don't know if I can explain myself. Example

Code 1:

```
Rect.Draw (color.red, 90.5)
```

this draws the red rectangle in its respective position

Code 2:

```
Rect.Draw (color.red, 90.5)
Rect.Draw (color.green, 100.5)
```

the code 2 it does not draw two rectangles. only respect the first and if i delete the first, the second being the only one will have priority.

Apparent solution: I would like to know how I can read RichTexbox line by line and treat each line as separate text. thus draw each rectangle procedurally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, RichTextBox has a `string[] Lines` property that you can use.

Also, this seems like a case basically begging to use regular expression (regex). Going by your code and the use of string magic you probably haven't heard of it before but regex is used for parsing strings and extracting information based on patterns. That is to say, pretty much exactly what you're trying to do here.

```cs
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

partial class Form1 : Form
{
  Regex rectRegex = null;
  private void ProcessRtf()
  {
    //init regex once.
    if(rectRegex == null)
      rectRegex = new Regex("Rect\.Draw\s*\(color\.(?<COL>[A-Za-z]+),\s+(?<POS>\d+(\.\d+)?)\)");

    foreach(string line in ScriptBox.Lines)
    {
      //for example: line = "Rect.Draw(color.red, 90.5)"
      var match = rectRegex.Match(line);
      if(match.Success)
      {
        string col = match.Groups["COL"].Value; //col = "red"
        string pos = match.Groups["POS"].Value; //pos = "90.5"

        //draw your rectangle

        break; //abort foreach loop.
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Your code works perfectly but the same thing keeps happening, the function ignores lines or times when "Rect.Draw" is written and still continues to draw only the first one it sees called

Comment: @Moix oh, I misunderstood your original post in that you _wanted_ only the first one drawn. Just remove the `break; //abort foreach loop` then and it should work for multiple lines. If it still doesn't work, maybe set a breakpoint and have a look at what `line` actually contains to make sure it really loops through lines properly.

Comment: Thanks it works. Could you pass me a web page or an article to delve into the subject of regular expressions?. Thank you very much for your help